# Pycharm debug and user permissions

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, erpnext

I am trying to debug Frappe Framework (based on Python) with PyCharm, the debugger works fine and breaks at the selected breakpoints in the code.

At the line

```
stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
```

where it is trying to open a log file for writing, I get Permission denied: */home/frappeuser/frappe-bench/logs/bench.log*. I "su ed" as root.

Frappe user is a sudo user, where I normally run the command bench start to start Frappe and it works fine from the command line, but not while I am debugging.

My question is why it is denying access to the log file when I am root. Not sure if PyCharm can be configured for different user levels.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not relevant to Pycharm, you have to change the permissions of that file so the working user can read the file. try `help chmod` or visit here http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html